Dose $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle f_k\rangle=\langle f\rangle$ imply $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k=f_k$ almost everywhere?
We know that for any $\langle f\rangle\in L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ there is a sequence $\{\langle f_k\rangle\}$ of elements of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, where each $f_k$ is a simple function that belongs to $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, such that
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{k\to\infty}\|\langle f_k\rangle-\langle f\rangle\|_p=\lim_{k\to\infty}d(\langle f_k\rangle,\langle f\rangle)=0;
\end{align*}
that is, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\langle f_k\rangle=\langle f\rangle$. Does this imply that for any $f\in\langle f\rangle$ and $f_k\in\langle f_k\rangle$ we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k=f$?
I think intuitively it is true, because every element in $\langle h\rangle$ agrees almost everywhere. But I am having a difficult time producing a formal proof. Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

Do you ask if there is a sequence of simple functions that converges almost everywhere, or if convergence in $L^p$ implies converges a.e.?

By $\langle f_k \rangle$ you mean the equivalence class?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Yes, the equivalence class, or the coset.

@mihaild I want to ask if $\langle f_k\rangle$ converges to $\langle f\rangle$ in $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ implies $f_k$ converges to $f$ in $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ almost everywhere (where $f_k\in\langle f_k\rangle$ and $f\in\langle f\rangle$).

Yes, because $|f-f_k|{\mathscr{L}^p}=|\langle f\rangle-\langle f_k\rangle|{L^p}$ for all $k$. Note that $|\cdot|_{\mathscr{L}^p}$ is not a norm but only a semi-norm, which is why we deal with $L^p$ instead of $\mathscr{L}^p$.

'$f_k$ conveges to $f$ in $\mathcal L^{p}$ almost everywhere' has no meaning.

@geetha290krm Yeah, I should have said $f_k$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere, where $f_k\in\mathscr{L}^p$ and $f\in\mathscr{L}^p$.
